# How to use Graph API to directly insert mail into an inbox

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to insert a message directly into a user's inbox using the Graph API /messages endpoint.

I am calling this endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}/mailFolders/inbox/messages
```

My request looks like this:

```
{
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "<a href='https://google.com'>test</a>"
    },
    "sender": {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "test",
            "address": "someuser@test2.com"
        }
    },
    "from": {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "test",
            "address": "someuser@test2.com"
        }
    },
    "toRecipients": [
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "Some User",
                "address": "someuser@test.com"
            }
        }
    ],
    "isDraft": false
}
```

It does put the message in the user's inbox, and it does NOT show up in the drafts folder. However, when I open the message in the inbox, it appears to be a draft. How can I directly insert a message into a users' inbox?

Comment: In the definition of the api resources, the action of create resources only create a Draft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0 Maybe for security reasons this endpoint is not available, because if someone gain access can introduce fake emails into users inboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the pidtagmessageflags singleValueExtendedProperties https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagmessageflags-canonical-property to either 1 (if you want the message marked as read also) or 4 (for unread). eg

```
{
"body": {
    "contentType": "html",
    "content": "<a href='https://google.com'>test</a>"
},
"sender": {
    "emailAddress": {
        "name": "test",
        "address": "someuser@test2.com"
    }
},
"from": {
    "emailAddress": {
        "name": "test",
        "address": "someuser@test2.com"
    }
},
"toRecipients": [
    {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "Some User",
            "address": "someuser@test.com"
        }
    }
],    
"singleValueExtendedProperties": [
    {
        "id": "Integer 0x0E07",
        "value": "4"
    }
]

}
```